OneDrive notification non-stop
I am getting bombarded with notifications from my alert bar stating OneDrive needs updating, but I can't find the software easily. I'm not sure where to look or how to update it. I don't want to break my notifications, just either uninstall or update the app to get the issue resolved.



I am getting bombarded with notifications from my alert bar stating OneDrive needs updating. but I cant find the software easily I'm not sure where to look or how to update it. I don't want to brake my notifications just either uninstall or update the app to get the issue to be resolved

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
Install the client the correct way, by following these instructions: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md
This will have the net effect:

It will get you to the correct client version for your platform

It will stop those notifications about the client needing to be updated

When a new client version is released, you will be able to just update your platform and the client will upgrade:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade



so there is no version out for the newest version of ubuntu?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble
that is what im runnning I tried re-installing but it dint seam to work I could not find my one drive anywhere.

The instructions are there for 'noble'. Please read: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md#distribution-ubuntu-2404 to install on 'Noble'

abraunegg, thank you for supporting linux ! Just a suggestion: can you to put an "OK" button on the dialog and make it disappear for good, or maybe repeat after one week or something. Also, in my case, your app works perfectly fine even without update (Debian 12 here).
